# PHP Soap Response String Array

Tags: php, soap

Here is the SOAP Object I am working with viewed via SOAPUI:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetPatientsResponse xmlns="http://interface.sitename.com/api">
         <GetPatientsResult><![CDATA[<GetPatients FacilityId="test" ActiveOnly="True" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><PatientList><Patient>
      <Id>1b518b28-4781-40a0-8358-a4f801178885</Id>
      <LastName>Test123</LastName>
      <NickName xsi:nil="true" />
      <Gender>F</Gender>
      <Physician xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ArrivalDate>2015-08-18T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
      <DepartureDate>2035-08-18T00:00:00</DepartureDate>
      <MedCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MedCartId>
      <TreatmentCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TreatmentCartId>
      <PictureUrl>https://interface.quickmar.com/beta/image_gen/pat1b518b28-4781-40a0-8358-a4f801178885.png</PictureUrl>
      <DOB>1900-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
      <SSNLastDigits xsi:nil="true" />
      <FacilityPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <PharmacyPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsAssessmentNeeded>false</IsAssessmentNeeded>
      <IsRedFlagged>false</IsRedFlagged>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
      <Id>642e39bc-d9e0-48e7-9c43-a4f801254b1e</Id>
      <FirstName>Allie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Assisted</LastName>
      <RoomNumber>302</RoomNumber>
      <NickName />
      <Gender>F</Gender>
      <Physician>Frank Jones</Physician>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ArrivalDate>1999-12-15T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
      <DepartureDate>2035-08-18T00:00:00</DepartureDate>
      <MedCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MedCartId>
      <TreatmentCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TreatmentCartId>
      <PictureUrl>https://interface.quickmar.com/beta/image_gen/pat642e39bc-d9e0-48e7-9c43-a4f801254b1e.png</PictureUrl>
      <DOB>1965-12-19T00:00:00</DOB>
      <SSNLastDigits>a1772</SSNLastDigits>
      <FacilityPatientId>1005</FacilityPatientId>
      <PharmacyPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsAssessmentNeeded>false</IsAssessmentNeeded>
      <IsRedFlagged>false</IsRedFlagged>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
      <Id>98f0e2de-d165-4643-9c11-a4e900eb5818</Id>
      <FirstName>Charlie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Jones</LastName>
      <RoomNumber>101</RoomNumber>
      <NickName>Mr. Charlie</NickName>
      <Gender>M</Gender>
      <Allergies />
      <Diagnoses />
      <Physician />
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ArrivalDate>2011-04-04T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
      <DepartureDate>2035-08-03T00:00:00</DepartureDate>
      <MedCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MedCartId>
      <TreatmentCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TreatmentCartId>
      <PictureUrl>https://interface.quickmar.com/beta/image_gen/pat98f0e2de-d165-4643-9c11-a4e900eb5818.png</PictureUrl>
      <DOB>1971-10-31T00:00:00</DOB>
      <SSNLastDigits xsi:nil="true" />
      <FacilityPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <PharmacyPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsAssessmentNeeded>false</IsAssessmentNeeded>
      <Diet />
      <IsRedFlagged>false</IsRedFlagged>
    </Patient></PatientList></GetPatients>]]></GetPatientsResult>
      </GetPatientsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My PHP Code:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://remoteapi.asmx?wsdl');
$params = array('facilityId' => 'test',
                'authId'     => 'biglongauthcode',
                'activeOnly' => true);

$response = $soapClient->GetPatients($params);
```

If I do execute:

```
var_dump($response);
```

I get:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetPatientsResult"]=> string(2944) " 1b518b28-4781-40a0-8358-a4f801178885 Test123 F true 2015-08-18T00:00:00 2035-08-18T00:00:00 
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 https://interface.api.com/beta/image_gen/pat1b518b28-4781-40a0-8358-a4f801178885.png 
1900-01-01T00:00:00 false false 642e39bc-d9e0-48e7-9c43-a4f801254b1e Allie Assisted 302 F Frank Jones true 1999-12-15T00:00:00 2035-08-18T00:00:00 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 https://interface.api.com/beta/image_gen/pat642e39bc-d9e0-48e7-9c43-a4f801254b1e.png 1965-12-19T00:00:00 a1772 1005 false false 98f0e2de-
d165-4643-9c11-a4e900eb5818 Charlie Jones 101 Mr. Charlie M true 2011-04-04T00:00:00 2035-08-03T00:00:00 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
https://interface.api.com/beta/image_gen/pat98f0e2de-d165-4643-9c11-a4e900eb5818.png 1971-10-02T00:00:00 false false " }
```

I've also run the following code:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $xml = htmlentities($value);
}
echo "<pre>".$xml;
```

This only iterates one time, because the entire dataset is in a single array value.  The output from above is:

```
<GetPatients FacilityId="test" ActiveOnly="True" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><PatientList><Patient>
      <Id>1b518b28-4781-40a0-8358-a4f801178885</Id>
      <LastName>Test123</LastName>
      <NickName xsi:nil="true" />
      <Gender>F</Gender>
      <Physician xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ArrivalDate>2015-08-18T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
      <DepartureDate>2035-08-18T00:00:00</DepartureDate>
      <MedCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MedCartId>
      <TreatmentCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TreatmentCartId>
      <PictureUrl>https://interface.api.com/beta/image_gen/pat1b518b28-4781-40a0-8358-a4f801178885.png</PictureUrl>
      <DOB>1900-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
      <SSNLastDigits xsi:nil="true" />
      <FacilityPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <PharmacyPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsAssessmentNeeded>false</IsAssessmentNeeded>
      <IsRedFlagged>false</IsRedFlagged>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
      <Id>642e39bc-d9e0-48e7-9c43-a4f801254b1e</Id>
      <FirstName>Allie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Assisted</LastName>
      <RoomNumber>302</RoomNumber>
      <NickName />
      <Gender>F</Gender>
      <Physician>Frank Jones</Physician>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ArrivalDate>1999-12-15T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
      <DepartureDate>2035-08-18T00:00:00</DepartureDate>
      <MedCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MedCartId>
      <TreatmentCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TreatmentCartId>
      <PictureUrl>https://interface.api.com/beta/image_gen/pat642e39bc-d9e0-48e7-9c43-a4f801254b1e.png</PictureUrl>
      <DOB>1965-12-19T00:00:00</DOB>
      <SSNLastDigits>a1772</SSNLastDigits>
      <FacilityPatientId>1005</FacilityPatientId>
      <PharmacyPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsAssessmentNeeded>false</IsAssessmentNeeded>
      <IsRedFlagged>false</IsRedFlagged>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
      <Id>98f0e2de-d165-4643-9c11-a4e900eb5818</Id>
      <FirstName>Charlie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Jones</LastName>
      <RoomNumber>101</RoomNumber>
      <NickName>Mr. Charlie</NickName>
      <Gender>M</Gender>
      <Allergies />
      <Diagnoses />
      <Physician />
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <ArrivalDate>2011-04-04T00:00:00</ArrivalDate>
      <DepartureDate>2035-08-03T00:00:00</DepartureDate>
      <MedCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</MedCartId>
      <TreatmentCartId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</TreatmentCartId>
      <PictureUrl>https://interface.quickmar.com/beta/image_gen/pat98f0e2de-d165-4643-9c11-a4e900eb5818.png</PictureUrl>
      <DOB>1971-10-02T00:00:00</DOB>
      <SSNLastDigits xsi:nil="true" />
      <FacilityPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <PharmacyPatientId xsi:nil="true" />
      <IsAssessmentNeeded>false</IsAssessmentNeeded>
      <Diet />
      <IsRedFlagged>false</IsRedFlagged>
    </Patient></PatientList></GetPatients>
```

The problem is I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I want to operate on the $response object by using code such as:

```
$lname = $response->Patient->Id
```

Or whatever the combination would be, I've been at this for so many hours straight now with nothing working, I realize once I get the $response object correctly broken down into key value pairs I will go back to messing around with ways to manipulate the data, but right now it is acting like a giant string and I cannot get anything out of it.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have searched for hours and not seen anyone else that has this problem with all data being in a single array value.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone else out in the future, but here is the solution:

You want to replace:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $xml = htmlentities($value);
}
```

With:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $xml = html_entity_decode($value);
```

This will remove all the html tags, and leave you with a clean XML file.  To be able to parse the file use simpleXML as follows:

```
$residents = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Now you can access the data like an array.  For instance, if I wanted to print the value from the Id attribute of the first patient I simply use the following line of code:

```
echo "First Resident ID: ".$residents->PatientList->Patient[0]->Id;
```